# How can I select tabitem in usercontrol from MainWindow

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I would like to ask you, how can I access my usercontrol from MainWindow?

For accessing to MainWindow I'm using :

```
Dim mw As MainWindow = DirectCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow)
```

I need this because I would like to select particular TabItem from my UserControl. (tabitem.IsSelected= true). UserControl is already placed in Grid on MainWindow as a child.

Thank you in advance

Comment: does your user control have any name? is it binded to something?

Comment: Yes. x:Name="employeemenu", and set to "public"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple way is to create a ReadOnly property in MainWindow returning the user control instance

eg

```
Public ReadOnly Property MyEmployeeMenu As UserControl
    Get
        Return Me.employeemenu
    End Get
End Property
```

usage

```
Dim mw As MainWindow = DirectCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow)
Dim empMenu as UserControl = mw.MyEmployeeMenu 'this way you can access the control
```